# Is it possible to apply laplace transform to solve this equation?

Tags: laplace-transform

I want to solve the below equation to get find a general solution for $\theta(t)$. Is the next step acceptable or do I have to take into account $\dot{L}$ as well ?
$$
\ddot{\theta} = -2 \frac{\dot{L}}{L}\dot{\theta}
$$
Applying laplace transform,

$$
s^2\phi(s)-s\theta(0) - \ddot{\theta}(0) = -2 \frac{\dot{L}}{L}[s \phi(s) - \theta(0)]
$$

Comment: You can't do that, You have to integrate everything with respect to $t$, not just the $\theta$ parts.

Comment: You might note that $\dfrac{d}{dt} (L^2 \dot{\theta}) = 2 \dot{L} \dot{\theta} + L \ddot{\theta} = 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That is a much simpler way to solve this equation. Thank you for your help!